# A sequence of holomorphic functions defined on a region such that $\Re f_n(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that if $U$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$ and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on $U$ such that $\Re (f_n(z))>0$ for every $n$ and every $z\in U$, then $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that either
>
> 1. $f_{n_k}(z)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $U$ to a holomorphic funcntion $f(z)$,
>
> or
>
> 2. $f_{n_k}(z)$ converges to $\infty$ (that is, $|f_{n_k}|\to\infty$) uniformly on compact subsets of $U$.

---

I have no idea about this. If $U$ were the whole complex plane, then $f_n(z)$ would be constant and everything is obvious. But if $U$ is not $\mathbb C$, then we cannot apply Liouville's theorem to $f_n(z)$ and I don't know how to use the condition that $\Re (f_n(z))>0$.

Comment: Knowing $\Re f>0$ tells you something about $1/(f+1)$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental result that is used here is:

$\Re{a}>0$ if and only if $|\frac{1-a}{1+a}|<1$

which gives the usual transform between the right-hand half-plane and the unit disc

(proof is just by squaring the RHS and noting that it is $1-\frac{4\Re{a}}{|1+a|^2}$

So we use $g_n=\frac{f_n-1}{f_n+1}$, $|g_n|<1$ so they form a normal family,

while from the relation $f_n=\frac{1+g_n}{1-g_n}$ we either have $g_n \to 1$ compactly, so $f_n \to \infty$ compactly,

or there is a convergent normal subsequence of $g_n \to g, g$ not identically $1$

(and hence by maximum modulus $|g|<1$),

so the corresponding subsequence of $f_n$ converges normally to $f=\frac{1+g}{1-g}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I haven't seen the equivalent statement before, and I don't know much about normal family. Could you recommend some materials to me so that I can take my lessons?

Comment: any standard introductory book on complex variables should have a discussion of the fundamental results about normal families (Vitali, Montel, etc); also you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_family